# Weird LINQ behaviour

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement, ternary-operator

I have this code:

here I get list of longs from the database:

```
IQueryable<long> query = from t in table select t.LongId
```

and here I try to get max from those IDs:

```
long max = query.Any() ? query.Max() : 0;
```

but no matter hwo much longs there are in the result of query, max is always set to 0.

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: How about debugging it? What does query.Any() return, what does query.Max() return?

Comment: 1) Is there some other code between these two lines? 2) What is `table` and what data it has?

Comment: are you sure query is not empty?

Comment: Why would you want to check `Any()` condition? Also - please do not downvote the naswers just because they did not solve your problem - that's not how SO works.

Comment: if you change the else condition to -1, does max return -1?

Comment: I don't want to get a downvote, so I just leave a comment: It's impossible, your code is ok. The problem is in your data: either your table is empty or your LongIds are less or equals to zero :)

Comment: @Tarec `Any()` prevents invalid operation exception when `Max()` is called on empty collection.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Somehow `DefaultIfEmpty().Max()` felt better, although they do exactly the same.

Comment: the query returns 2 results - so Any() returns true..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If

```
long max = query.Any() ? query.Max() : 0;
```

returns zero, then one of following is true:

1. Query does not return any results
2. Max value in query results is zero

First case is possible when you modify your table between defining query and getting max value from query. Remember - `query` does not have any data. It's only query definition, and you will get   data only when you execute query (e.g. call Any() or Max()).

Test:

```
List<long> table = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3 };
var query = from t in table select t; // query is not executed
table.Clear(); // modify data source before query is executed
Assert.False(query.Any()); // execute query on modified data source
```

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't this be simpler?

```
long max = table.OrderByDescending(t => t.LongId)
                .Select(t => t.LongId)
                .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way:

```
var maxId = table.OrderByDescending(x => x.LongId).First().LongId;
```